# Resolvent in French

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, ho.history-overview, galois-theory

First, I apologize if the question doesn't fit this forum.
In a thread about Galois theory on a French math forum, I read "le sextique résolvent" and the spelling looks odd to me. I would have expected an ending in "ant" for this notion, as the derivate of a present participle.

I am therefore looking for references in French freely available online where this notion and its use are introduced and hopefully motivated. I would also like to know if this notion dates back to Galois himself or was introduced later and when.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although @ACL gave a nice [answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/255682/2383), probably this question, and [your follow-up](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/255680/resolvent-in-french#comment629636_255682), belong on [HSM](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on hsm.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should read "la résolvante sextique".

Resolvents were used before Galois - and are still used after him. For example the cubic resolvent that appears in the solution of the fourth degree equation is sometimes attributed to Lagrange. In fact Lagrange had already studied the permutations of roots of a polynomial equation and how some of them fix a given form.

Comment: Thank you very much. Another historical weird point to me is that Galois is credited for the first use of the word "groupe", how then did Lagrange call the objects he dealt with ?

Comment: you can see for yourself in http://sites.mathdoc.fr/cgi-bin/oeitem?id=OE_LAGRANGE__3_205_0  the documents are searchable. For instance I did not find "groupe" in the Section troisieme

Comment: Thank you. I was also referring to Lagrange's theorem saying that the order of a subgroup of a group G divides the order of G : I really wonder how he stated it without giving a name to objects like G.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Lagrange's own version of his theorem was not about abstract groups, but instead was about permutations of polynomials. He talked about counting the number of different polynomials you get by permuting the variables in a polynomial in n variables, and his theorem was that this number is a factor of $n!$.  Today we'd say this is counting the size of an orbit for the permutation action of the group $S_n$ on polynomials in $n$ indeterminates: for a polynomial $f$, its $S_n$-orbit is given by the orbit-stabilizer formula as $|S_n|/|{\rm Stab}_f|$, which  divides $|S_n| = n!$.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN a Google search on "Lagrange's theorem history" brings up a paper that you might want to look at to see the original setting of Lagrange's theorem and how it became the version we use today: Richard L. Roth, A History of Lagrange's Theorem on Groups, Mathematics Magazine 74 (2001), 99-108.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN your first comment says Galois was the first to use the term groupe in its usual mathematical meaning.  What he meant by groupe was a group of permutations, i.e., a subgroup of some $S_n$. Abstract groups, not a priori assumed to be a subgroup of $S_n$, were defined only much later.  You can presumably find discussions of this by searching online with keywords like "history group theory".

Comment: The Roth paper referenced by @KConrad is at http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690624 .